# Output of a c++ program

Tags: c++, prefix, operator-precedence, postfix-notation

While I was trying to improve my c++ knowledge, I found this problem from an old programming contest. I will try to enter the contest this year so I want to be prepared.

What is the output for the following program?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int dat=1;
int counter=0;

class ClassB;

class B {

  public: 
          virtual void f(int d=5)=0;
          };

class A {

  unsigned i;
  public:
         int pod;
         int index;


         A& operator++() { cout<<"A "<<pod--<<dat++<<endl; A* b=new A;  return *b; }
         A operator++(int) {cout<<"B "<<pod++<<dat--<<endl; A* b=new A;  return *b;}
         A& operator--() {cout<<"C "<<dat++ <<++pod<<endl; A* b=new A;  return *b;}
         A operator--(int) {cout<<"D "<<dat--<<--pod<<endl; A* b=new A;  return *b;}
         void operator+(A& b) {cout<<"Addition Index "<<index<<endl; pod++;}

         friend void B::f(int);
         A() : i(0), pod(dat) {pod++; index=++counter; cout<<"CA "<<"Index "<<index<<endl; }
         ~A(){pod++; cout<<"DA Index "<<index<<endl;}

};              


 const ClassB& returnClassA(const ClassB& p) {return p;}


class ClassB: public A, public B {
    public:
         void f(int d=2){A c; c++; pod*=d--;}
         ClassB(){cout<<"CB Index "<<index<<endl;}
         ~ClassB(){cout<<"DB Index "<<index<<endl;}
};


ClassB returnClassB(ClassB s) {return s;}

class ClassC : public ClassB {
  public:
         ClassC(){cout<<"CC Index "<<index<<endl;}
         ~ClassC(){cout<<"DC Index "<<index<<endl;}
};

ClassB returnClassC(ClassB s){return s;}

int main()
{           
    ClassC x;      
    A v,w;               
    B *c = new ClassB;   

   --++v--+++w;

   returnClassC(returnClassB(returnClassA(x))); 

   return 0;

}
```

This is supposed to be solved on paper, but because I am beginner I used compiler. 
Also, the variables counter and index were added by me so I can keep track of the objects that are being created. The original expression was --++v--+++w--; but I changed it with --++v--+++w; because the compiler was giving me errors.

The part:

```
ClassC x;      
A v,w;               
B *c = new ClassB;
```

outputs :

1. CA Index 1
2. CB Index 1
3. CC Index 1
4. CA Index 2
5. CA Index 3
6. CA Index 4
7. CB Index 4

Which I understand.

I have problem understanding the next expression, --++v--+++w; so at first I tried understanding the output of --++v--++; and then I would add +w.

The output of --++v--++; is:

1. D 11
2. CA Index 5
3. B 10
4. CA Index 6
5. A 0 -1
6. CA Index 7
7. C 02
8. CA Index 8
9. DA Index 6
10. DA Index 5

This means that the order of the operations is --(++((v--)++)).
Why is this so? Is there some rule as to which operations are evaluated first?
Also I don't understand why the destructors of the objects with Index 6 and 5 are called?

If I use the original expression, --++v--+++w; ,
the output is:

1. D 11
2. CA Index 5
3. B 10
4. CA Index 6
5. A 0 -1
6. CA Index 7
7. C 02
8. CA Index 8
9. Addition Index 8
10. DA Index 6
11. DA Index 5

Why the +w operation is evaluated last? Is it because of the operator precedence?
Also, I found out that if I write cout << v.index it would return 2, meaning v is still the original object created before. So where do the objects with indexes 5-8 go? How can I access them?

The last part, returnClassC(returnClassB(returnClassA(x)));
outputs:

1. DB Index 1
2. DA Index 1
3. DB Index 1
4. DA Index 1
5. DB Index 1
6. DA Index 1

I don't understand why the destructors are called?

Comment: I honest don't think cracking silly code like this is the best way to improve C++ knowledge

Comment: Don't waste your time on **** like this.

Comment: @Nikola - If it is that hard to tell what the code does, it's just not useful. You will never, ever write anything like this. The goal is to write code that *obviously* works correctly, not code that nobody can understand. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson - i found this problem as part of OOP contest. The contest is very popular and recognized, i don't know why they would would give this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to note
When you are overloading operators in C++ there are some things to know, for example ++ you caneither do a preincrement

```
++i
```

or a post increment

```
i++
```

in order to tell the compiler which you are overloading you'll need to have no parameters or an int in the signature

```
A operator++(int)
```

is overloading the post incremennt,

```
A& operator++()
```

overloads pre increment

In C++ an object's desctructor is called in two cases

1. You call delete on a pointer to an object you allocated using new

   ```
   A* = new A(); //constructor is called
   delete(A);//destructor is called
   ```
2. You leave context for an object created on the stack

   ```
   if(something) {
       A a();
       ...
   } //here a's destructor is called because a no longer exists
   ```

Notice in your code how some operators return a copy, others return a reference.

```
A operator++(int)
```

this function is returning a copy. This means that when you call this particular function the constructor is being called once inside the function for the new A that is being called and then again when you return from the function as a copy of the object pointed to by b is being copied.

You can find some infromation on operator precedence [here] (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

I notice some people are tellign you it's useless to learn from code like this. I agree that coding in this way is pretty bad, but it can teach you a lot about how constructors/destructors, heap/stack and operators work in C++. There are probably better ways of learning, this seems pretty 'mid-term examy' to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the concepts of post/pre increment , and i understand the code. What i don't understand is as i said the order they are called when we have expression like --++v--+++w. Which comes first and why?

Comment: the link i sent tells you which operators go right to left and which are left to right.

Comment: Oh i see now, i didn't understand what it mean by right to left and right to left, thanks. Cannot vote up, new member.

Comment: If you find it answers your question then you can always accept ;)

Comment: I still need to understand the returnClassC(returnClassB(returnClassA(x))); part

Comment: Look at the parameters and return types of the returnClassX functions. If you see something being returned by / passed by value, then a copy is being made and the constructor will be called, also once you leave the context where the object is being created the destructor gets called.